# Magento 2 Category field data scope issues

Tags: magento2, database, catalog, category-products

Good Afternoon,

I am looking at a data scoping issue around category content fields for Magento 2 (2.4.5-p2). I have a list of fields that we typically fill in (please see below for category content field list). I would like to run a check against the category data tables and find out which categories have these fields where scope is not default scope and order the results by "store_id > category > field" if possible. I have done similar scope db before checks for cms blocks / pages but I am struggling with the categories fields.

### Field List:

thumbnail

category image

category small image

category mobile image

Description

short description

sub title

additional content

featured block

Any help or guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check category data in Magento 2 and identify which categories have specific fields set to a scope other than the default, you can use a custom SQL query or script. Since you have experience with CMS blocks and pages, the process is somewhat similar for category fields. Here's a brief guide:

1. Access the Database: Connect to your Magento database using a tool like phpMyAdmin or through a database client.
2. Identify Relevant Tables: The category data is stored in tables like `catalog_category_entity`, `catalog_category_entity_varchar`, `catalog_category_entity_text`, etc. The `catalog_category_entity` table contains the base data, while the others store attribute values.
3. Custom SQL Query: Write a SQL query to join these tables. You'll need to join them on the `entity_id` column. Filter the results where the `attribute_id` corresponds to your fields of interest (e.g., thumbnail, category image) and where the `store_id` is not the default (usually `store_id` 0).
4. Order the Results: To order the results as per "store_id > category > field", include an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL query.
5. Execute the Query: Run the query in your database tool. Ensure to test it on a staging environment first to avoid any disruptions on your live site.
6. Scripting Option: If you're more comfortable with scripting, you can write a custom script in PHP or another language, utilizing Magento's APIs to fetch and filter the data.

Remember, direct database queries can be risky on a live site, so it's crucial to back up your database before making any direct queries or changes. Additionally, since you're dealing with Magento 2.4.5-p2, ensure that your approach aligns with any specific changes or requirements of this version. If you're unsure, consulting the Magento developer documentation or seeking assistance from the Magento community forums can be beneficial.

Comment: thanks for the advise, it was enough for me start building queries